# Magento Model returns empty data array

Tags: module, magento-1, model

Magento custom module model returns empty data array,what would be the issue.I am new to magento.Trying to create custom module.Please help me out.please check below screen[image]

/Model/Suites.php:

```
<?php

class Bespoke_Suites_Model_Suites extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract{

public function _construct(){
    parent::_construct();
    $this->_init('bespoke_suites/suites');
}
```

/Model/Resource/Suites.php :

```
<?php
class Bespoke_Suites_Model_Resource_Suites extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract{

public function _construct(){
    //parent::_construct();
    $this->_init('bespoke_suites/suites','suites_id');
}
}
```

config.xml

```
.....
<bespoke_suites_resource>
    <class>Bespoke_Suites_Model_Resource</class>
    <entities>
        <suites>
            <table>bespoke_suites</table>
        </suites>
    </entities>
</bespoke_suites_resource>
.....
```

Comment: try to dump $model->getData()

Comment: @razbakov      `Fatal error: Call to a member function getData()`

Comment: $model = Mage::getModel('bespoke_suites/suites')->load(1);
print_r($model->getData());

Comment: @razbakov       resource instance is not available means what in this case?

Answer (score 4):

So have you written any instances to your database?

Then load a specific instance (suite) and view its data:

```
/** @var Bespoke_Suites_Model_Suites $suite */
$suite = Mage::getModel('bespoke_suites/suites');
// Load suite with suites_id = 1
$suite->load(1);
```

If you have not yet created any suites, you may do so with:

```
/** @var Bespoke_Suites_Model_Suites $suite */
$suite = Mage::getModel('bespoke_suites/suites');

// Set whatever fields you have in your table
$suite->setName('foo');
// equivalent:
$suite->setData('name', 'foo');

// Save it
$suite->save();
// Should now have a suites_id set automatically
```

Comment: when i try your first code snippet,return in report file `a:5:{i:0;s:34:"Resource instance is not available";i:1;s:834:"#0 `

Comment: second part of your code returns `Fatal error: Call to a member function beginTransaction()`

Comment: Records are there in my table